# i want use google map v2 in all version of os without google play service, how can i make it

Tags: android, google-maps

To make the google map v2 work in all version of os ,i use layout bellow:

and the project can really launched,but there is a button in the view to fetching the google play services:

questions:

1. is there any method to make google map V2 work in any kind of end without fetching the google
   play services
2. if the answear of question 1 is no, can i fetching the google play services in silent(i dont like the button but only a map appear in my view, it is not good for user).
3. if above question cant be resolved, what can i do to make the geopoint appear on the google map .

Comment: Google maps V2 needs Google play services and attempting to circumvent this would surely be a breach of the TOS

Comment: do you mean that, maybe in the futher, google map can be use in the ends below version 3.1 without google play services?

Comment: Play store services are [available for 2.2 and up](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). On top of that, there is the `SupportMapFragment` to make coding easier for multiple platforms.

Comment: I use SupportMapFragment in the layout ,but it unabled to connect to the google server when i fetching the google play services using the google account.is there any solution to use the map ,it is so complicated to use google map V2.